# how for loop is getting evaluated when printf is used inside the loop in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>  
int main()
{  
  int x=1,y=1;  
  for( ; y; printf("%d %d\n",x,y))
    y=x++<=5;
}
```

Is the expression `y=x++<=5` is executed before the `for` loop? Is that `x` 
compared first and assign a value to `y` and then `x` is being incremented? The above snippet is giving below output.

```
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 1
7 0
```

Can anyone tell how the for loop is being evaluated?

Comment: The chapter about loops in your C programming book should answer how for loops work. If you know how a sane for loop like `for(int i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", array[i]);` works, then you can figure out how an insane one like in your example works from there.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. "How does a `for` loop work" and "How does this assignment work" are rather independent.

Comment: @Lundin, Sorry for the thing. I wanted to ask how those 2 statements were being evaluated.  i was not intended to ask for loop woking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before going to the actual problem you should know how the for loop works in steps:
For loop has 4 steps that is :

For example:

for(i=0;i<10;i++){

statement;

}

Step 1: first it will initialize i as 0;
Step 2: It will check the condition is satisfying or not;
Step 3: The it will go to the statement block and then it will perform the statement
step 4: It will increment the value .

But Here in your Question:

```
 #include<stdio.h>  
    int main(){  
    int x=1,y=1;  
    for(;y;printf("%d %d\n",x,y))
    y=x++<=5;
    }
```

Step 1 : It enter into the loop(i.e. 1 because it is blank)

Step 2 : Check the condition block which is one(i.e the y value is one)

Step 3 : Here first the post increment Logic is implemented.

First the x value is initialized that is one and the incremented.
The the condition x++<=5 is checked.

If x++<=5 it will initialize y to the value of 1 because the condition satisfy
else it will  initialize y to the value of 0 because the condition not satisfy.

****In First step of loop 
it will check 1 <= 5 true
so y = 1 and so on till the condition satisfy otherwise y = 0****

Step 4:It will print the value of x and y

Next : Again the pointer will go to condition block and then goes to second because y = 1
when y = 0  the loop will stop;
**It will not go to the initialization step from the second loop....

### As you can notice in the output.

Comment: @Moith,  Thank you very much. I got your point.

Comment: Your welcome buddy!!

Answer (score 0):

The loop gets called until `y == 0`. Then `x` gets incremented but `x++` returns the old value of `x`. After that the comparison runs and assigns its value to `y` (1 or 0). The `printf` function is exexuted after the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is some kind of puzzle, because nobody of decent sanity should write a loop like that.

Anyway, a statement block containing a for loop consists of 6 statement blocks (labelled `a` to `f`):

```
a
for (b ; c ; d) {
  e
}
f
```

The code is executed in the same order as if it was this `while` loop:

```
a
b
while (c) {
  e
  d
}
f
```

So basically your code is:

```
int x=1, y=1;
while (y) {
  y=x++<=5;
  printf("%d %d\n",x,y);
}
```